# How to database select query with limit in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to select records from database table here is query

```
 $select = $this->newDbConnection()
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getDbPrefix() . 'test', '*')
        ->order('id', 'ASC')
```

I want to limit result records lets say 500 recoreds per request.

final query would look like this

```
SELECT `test`.* FROM `test` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,500
```

How I can set limit**(LIMIT 0,500)** by magento2 way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
$select = $this->newDbConnection()
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getDbPrefix() . 'test', '*')
        ->order('id', 'ASC')
        ->limit(500, $offset);
```

Hope this helps.

***Note: Above code is not tested but it should work.***

Comment: Thank you that worked!